# Having Clause In Linq

Tags: linq

I have a query which is connecting two tables that is header and detail table and in the having clause i have to check whether total mark of the header should equal to the sum of the detail marks.

Query is :-

```
select h.ExamID,h.ExamID,max(h.TotalMark) as TotalMark
from ExamMasters h
join ExamDetails d on h.ExamID=d.ExamID
group by h.ExamID,h.ExamName
having max(h.TotalMark)=sum(d.Mark)
```

I just want to convert this query to linq syntax.
Can anybody help please.

Regards,
Ajith

Comment: and note that `group by` has a clause `into`, like `group h by new { h.ExamID,h.ExamName } into r`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: But i am not able to write the where clause in Linq to check that 
max(TotalMark)=sum(Mark)

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
var res = from h in ExamMasters
          join d in ExamDetails on h.ExamID equals d.ExamID
          group new { h, d } by new { h.ExamID, h.ExamName } into hdg
          let max = hdg.Max(x => x.h.TotalMark)
          where hdg.Sum(x => x.d.Mark) == max
          select new
          {
              hdg.Key.ExamID, hdg.Key.ExamName, TotalMark = max
          };
```

Note the use of `group` ... `by` ... `into` and the fact that to have both `h` and `d` after the group by I had to put them in a `new { h, d }`.

Comment: @AjithCholayil - If this answer helped you solve your problem please consider marking question as solved.